# GitHubに載ってるツールが使えない。

Tags: github

GitHubに載ってるツールやアプリケーションで使ってみたいものはたくさんあるんですけど、
リポジトリをクローンするところまでしか行かず、ツールを実行することができません。
何かのコマンドが必要なんでしょうか。アドバイスを頂けたら幸いです。
レベルの低い質問で申し訳ありません。

HyperspaceというマストドンというSNSのためのツールなんですが。 これが使えなくて困っています。
https://github.com/alicerunsonfedora/hyperspace

Answer (score 5):

成果物の配布方法はリポジトリによりけりな部分がありますが、質問で挙げられたリポジトリに関しては以下画像の赤枠で囲った「**release**」のリンクをクリックし、次のページでバージョンごと、プラットフォームごとにexeファイルなどが置いてあるので、利用しているOSに合わせて必要なファイルをダウンロードしてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

親切なリポジトリであればREADMEファイルやWikiページに手順が書いてあるので、そちらをよく確認してもらえればと思いますが、クローン(clone)は基本的に「ソースコードに手を加える人用」の手順です。

単に配布されているツール等を入手するだけであれば、今回紹介したreleaseページから入手するか、緑色の「Clone or download」ボタンからZIPファイルを保存するだけで済むケースがほとんどです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。助かりました。